# Computing probability of occurrence for all alphabets in map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, average, reducers

I am trying to calculate the probability of occurrence of each letter in a file using the Map-reduce program.

I am using the following framework for map-reduce.
1 mapper to map all the characters, For ex ('a',1). 1 combiner to compute the total of occurrences of each character. 1 reducer to compute the average.

However, I am unable to compute the average in the reducer. So, I have added a dummy character that will be written once whenever a new character is mapped by the mapper.

This dummy character represents the total number of characters, I do not know how to access the same in reducer and divide all other values by the total.

For ex, The following is the output of the combiner.

```
# 10
a 2
b 2
c 2
d 4
```

I tried with 1 reducer, which gives no output.

I particularly need to know the logic that has to be written in the reducer.

```java
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    int wordCount = 0;
    double total = 1;
    System.out.println("In Reducer now!");
    double avg = 0;
    total = values.iterator().next().get();

    avg = values.get() / total;
    context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(avg));
}
```

The above code writes nothing on the output.

Mapper

```java
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String s = value.toString();

    char[] arrayofChar = s.toCharArray();
    for (char ch : arrayofChar) {
        System.out.print(ch);
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            context.write(new Text(String.valueOf(ch)), new DoubleWritable(1));
            context.write(new Text("#"), new DoubleWritable(1));

        }
    }
}
```

Combiner

```java
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    double total = 0;
    System.out.println("In Combiner now!");
    for (DoubleWritable value : values) {
        total += value.get();
    }
    context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(total));
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run your code? You have to provide more information about objects wich id used: "values" variable, DoubleWritable class...

Comment: I have added code for Reducer, Combiner and Mapper.

Answer (score 0):

To declutter this I've written separate consumer:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception{
        String s= "aabccdaaab"; 
        Averager av = s.chars().collect(Averager::new,Averager::accept, Averager::combine);
        System.out.println(av.averages());
    }
}

class Averager implements IntConsumer  {
    private int count = 0;
    private Map<Character,Integer> data = new HashMap<>();
        
    public  Map<Character, Double>averages() {
        Map<Character, Double> result = new HashMap<>();
        for(Character c : data.keySet()) {
            double d = (double)data.get(c)/count;
            result.put(c,d);
        }
        return result;
    }
        
    public void accept(int c) { 
        Character cc = new Character((char)c);
        count++;
        if(data.containsKey(cc)) {
            int i = data.get(cc);
            i++;
            data.put(cc, i);
        } else {
            data.put(cc, 1);
        }
    }

    public void combine(Averager other) {
        for(Character c : data.keySet()) {
            if(other.data.containsKey(c)) {
                int sum = data.get(c) + other.data.get(c);
                other.data.put(c, sum);
            } else {
                other.data.put(c, data.get(c));
            }
        }
        data = other.data;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{a=0.5, b=0.2, c=0.2, d=0.1}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution using Java Streams, however the OP is apparently using [Hadoop MapReduce](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html) (the type names match his code).

Comment: Thanks. However, the required output for the given input is {a=.2,b=.2,c=.2d=.4}. Also, I am trying to solve the question using MapReduce.

Comment: It would be great if you give formulas/examples in OP  :) In my code I used input "aabccdaaab".

Comment: I have edited my original post now. Actual input I am reading from a file through driver class.